# How to get the class name?

Tags: yasnippet

I'm trying to devise a function which returns the class name. I would like to call that function inside a Yasnippet snippet for PHP-mode, so the class name will be inserted inside the template snippet.

After reading Emacs documentation, I found `which-function-mode`, which it returns a function name. But nothing about class names, unfortunately. Do anyone know a alternative way to get the class name of the position/current buffer?

Edit: I found an regex in the imenu source code that matches the name of the classes in PHP. But now I'm wondering how he could returns the result for yasnippet:   `("^\\s-*\\(?:\\(?:abstract\\|final\\)\\s-+\\)?class\\s-+\\(\\(?:\\sw\\|\\\\\\|\\s_\\)+\\)" 1)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
(defun foobar ()
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (call-interactively 'move-end-of-line)
    (search-backward-regexp "^\\s-*\\(?:\\(?:abstract\\|final\\)\\s-+\\)?class\\s-+\\(\\(?:\\sw\\|\\\\\\|\\s_\\)+\\)")
    (let ((ret (match-string 1)))
      (message ret)
      ret)))
```

If the cursor is inside a class definition then calling `foobar` gives the class name.

Comment: Could you specify more about that, for example, to get the class name? When I do
the following:  http://pastebin.com/Gs90Y64q and call `M-x foobar` inside a PHP
class then I get the error message: 
`foobar: Search failed: "^\\s-*\\(?:\\(?:abstract\\|final\\)\\s-+\\)?class\\s-+\\(\\(?:\\sw\\|\\\\\\|\\s_\\)+\\)"`

Comment: If you're inside the class, you should probably be searching backwards, not forwards.

Comment: I fixed the answer.

Comment: You should just use `(move-end-of-line 1)`, no need for `call-interactively`. Possibly using `(end-of-line)` would be better.